# For the IPython run magic the option to ignore SystemExist doesn't seem to work with modules

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, pytest, spyder

The docs for the `%run` magic `-e` option state:

> ignore sys.exit() calls or SystemExit exceptions in the script being
>   run. This is particularly useful if IPython is being used to run
>   unittests, which always exit with a sys.exit() call. In such cases you
>   are interested in the output of the test results, not in seeing a
>   traceback of the unittest module.

This works when running scripts but doesn't seem to work when running modules.
So when I type `%run -e -m pytest` I still get a traceback when a test fails due the `SystemExit` thrown by pytest which is case mentioned in the docs above that `-e` is meant to address. I know I can type !`pytest` but I don't want to wait until `pytest` completed before I start to see results, and I also want to add the current directory to to module search path.

I am running IPython within Spyder but the behaviour is the same if I run IPython from the Windows command prompt. I there any way of doing what I want and avoiding the distracting traceback?

I ran the following test with `%run -m pytest` from the spyder  ipython console

```
import pytest

def test_fail():
    assert 0
```

The output was:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: D:\home\shane\temp\pytest
collected 1 item

test_dummy.py F                                                          [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_fail __________________________________

    def test_fail():
>       assert 0
E       AssertionError

test_dummy.py:21: AssertionError
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
FAILED test_dummy.py::test_fail - AssertionError
============================== 1 failed in 0.03s ==============================
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\opt\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)

  File "c:\opt\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)

  File "c:\opt\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)

  File "c:\opt\python37\lib\site-packages\pytest\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise SystemExit(pytest.main())

SystemExit: ExitCode.TESTS_FAILED
```

Comment: `pytest` doesn't raise `SystemExit` by itself. Is it a test that raises a `SystemExit`? Please give a [mcve] if possible.

Comment: @hoefling - have updated my question with a specific example